# Как сделать что бы музыка играла на фоне программы, а не вместо неё

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо "впихнуть" музыку на задний фон, но она выполняется как код и пока не завершит выполнение код дальше не воспроизводится.

Comment: Какой функцией музыку включаете?

Comment: PlaySound(TEXT("Riders.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);

Comment: Замените параметр на `SND_ASYNC` и будет вам счастье. Если сработает, напишу полноценный ответ.

Comment: К сожалению совсем перестало воспроизводить данный аудио файл.

Comment: Ладно, тогда попробуйте `SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME`.

Comment: Проблема осталась нерешенной. Аудио файл воспроизводится до конца и только потом выполняется код, который записан далее.

Comment: Странно, у меня все работает. [Попробуйте этот код](https://pastebin.com/0SEGda30). Хотя, я проверял на гцц вместо студии, но это не должно влиять на результат.

Comment: Да, действительно работает, постараюсь подстроить под свой код. Огромное Вам спасибо, да здоровья побольше :)

Comment: Отлично. Поставьте тогда галочку на ответе снизу. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Почитал мануал.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx)

Все дело во флажке `SND_SYNC`. Замените его на `SND_ASYNC`, и функция будет завершаться мгновенно, оставляя музыку играть в фоне.

Еще, на всякий случай лучше добавить флажок `SND_FILENAME`, означающий, что звук надо достать из файла.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("Riders.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
```